# List files of a directory on remote PC (error access denied) C#

Tags: c#, .net

I try to list all the files of a directory on a remote PC but when I run the code I have this error :
"Access to the path is denied" but I can access to the path with the file explorer. Is there any way to fix this error?

Code used to connect to remote PC :

```
try
{
    CimCredential Credentials = new CimCredential(PasswordAuthenticationMechanism.Default, domain, username, securepassword);

    WSManSessionOptions SessionOptions = new WSManSessionOptions();
    SessionOptions.AddDestinationCredentials(Credentials);

    CimSession Session = CimSession.Create(computer, SessionOptions);

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("erreur : " + ex);
}
```

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is must mean is that you have Admin privilege on both machines.  So in VS you have to start VS by right click and and select Run Ad Admin. The you do not need credentials if the Explorer doesn't ask for credentials.  Also in c# when you are using ADMIN instead of the colon (\\servername\c:\path) use a dollar sign (\\servername\c$\path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to execute a net use command before to connect to the remote pc

code :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "net";
        startInfo.Arguments = "use path /user:username password";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```